# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'UITableViewDataDelegate'

Tags: cocoa-touch, delegates, protocols, uitableview

I'm new to app development and am trying to follow '*Learning* iPhone Programming'by Alasdair Allan (O'Reilly, 2010) but xcode isn't agreeing with the book.

It's bringing up the error 'Cannot find protocol declaration for 'UITableViewDataDelegate' on:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootController : UIViewController 
    <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataDelegate>
{
    UITableView *tableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

I've found a lot of similar questions about not finding protocol declarations but not much on UITableViewDataDelegate. I'm sure this is a relatively easy fix, but like I said, I'm very new to app development and am not to great at problem solving yet!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such protocol, the right name is `UITableViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

You're confused between the dataSource and delegate protocol names in `UITableView`:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDataSource> dataSource

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate
```

so you're interface should read:

```
@interface RootController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```